# How to test Unity Ads?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, ads

I've got Unity 5.2 and I want to load an ad every time when I load a new scene. I added the Unity ad code into my script that changes the scene when I press a button. Here's the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;


public class UI1 : MonoBehaviour
{
public void ShowAd()
{
    if (Advertisement.IsReady())
    {
        Advertisement.Show();
    }
}


public void ChangeToScene(int sceneToChangeTo)
{
    Application.LoadLevel(sceneToChangeTo);
}
}
```

How do I test to see if the script loads ads? I haven't published the app to the Google Play Store but I want to make sure the ads work.

I've tried using logs, but only "Changed Scene" showed when changing scenes.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;


public class UI1 : MonoBehaviour
{
public void ShowAd()
{
    if (Advertisement.IsReady())
        Debug.Log("Line 1 of ad script worked!");
    {
        Advertisement.Show();
        Debug.Log("Line 2 of ad script worked, might be showing ads!!");
    }

}


public void ChangeToScene(int sceneToChangeTo)
{
    Application.LoadLevel(sceneToChangeTo);
    Debug.Log("Changed scene!");
}
}
```

Comment: The app does not have to be published to Google Play in order for ads to work. If this is your only concern - there should be no problem. Or did you try to run it on a device and got some error?

Comment: When I package up the project to an .apk and install on a Samsung Tab 3, it works fine, but no ads show, there is no change with or without the ad script. However, when I run in the Unity Editor on the bottom it says- "UnityAdsEditor: Initialize(1018009, True);
UnityEditor.Advertisements.UnityAdsEditor:EditorOnLoad()"- Does "true" mean that there is an ad?

Comment: It means the ads are initialized, but nothing more. When the ad is shown in editor, you are supposed to see a blue screen saying "your ad is here" or something of that sort.

Comment: Is the code you posted all you have? Do you call ShowAd() from somewhere?

Comment: Didn't use ShowAd() at all

Comment: Check my updated code above as you see I tried to run the Debug.log but it doesn't work for the AD code, but works for the Change Scene code. Sorry if I'm a noob, I'm not great at scripting :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem is that you simply never call `Advertisement.Show()`. It is not called automatically on scene load or something, you have to call it. So, for example, you can modify your code a little, something like this:

```
public class UI1 : MonoBehaviour 
{ 

    void Start() {
        // We use coroutine and not calling Show() directly because
        // it is possible that at this point ads are not initialized yet
        StartCoroutine(ShowAds());
    }

    IEnumerator ShowAds() {
        if (Advertisement.IsReady()) { 
            Advertisement.Show();
            yield break;
        }
        // Ads are not initialized yet, wait a little and try again
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        if (Advertisement.IsReady()) { 
            Advertisement.Show();
            yield break;
        }

        Debug.LogError("Something wrong");
    }

    public void ChangeToScene(int sceneToChangeTo) { 
        Application.LoadLevel(sceneToChangeTo);
    } 
}
```

You will also need to place an object of type UI1 in each scene, so that Start() function will be called in each scene.

You can continue from here. Actually there are many different ways to do it, here ads are called on each scene start, but you can also do, for example, before scene loads by modifying ChangeScene() function, or make one indestructible game object monitoring OnLevelWasLoaded() etc.

Comment: Thanks! Works like magic now! I see a blue screen saying "This would be your Ad unit, things seem to be working!". Obviously every scene is too many ads, so I created another script with your code that I can assign to objects in some scenes, and set UI1 to load scenes without ads.  Awarded best answer :D